# Angular-CLI: Unexpected Token < in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, heroku, angular-cli

I am new to Angular so please bear with me. Currently working on a website that I uploaded through Heroku but I am getting the following `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error in the chrome dev tool console:

```
jquery-2.2.3.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
bootstrap.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.viewport.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
hoverIntent.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
superfish.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.fancybox.pack.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
revolution.extension.actions.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
revolution.extension.carousel.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
revolution.extension.migration.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
revolution.extension.navigation.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
revolution.extension.parallax.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
revolution.extension.video.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
owl.carousel.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.stellar.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
isotope.pkgd.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.placeholder.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.validate.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.form.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
gmap3.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.easypiechart.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquerysimplecounter.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
odometer.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
chart.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
instafeed.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
twitterfetcher.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.mb.ytplayer.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
jquery.countdown.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
wow.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
shim.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
zone.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
custom.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Now, all my files are under `src/assets/js` folder and are called in the `head` section of my `index.html`. I had them first in the scripts section under `angular-cli.json`, it would work fine when in development. When I uploaded everything into production through Heroku, I would get a multi script error. The reason was that in that script section, it only accepts plugins installed through `npm` and kept under `node_modules`. So I did some research and decided to apply my scripts into the `head` section of my `index.html`. Now the issue is that when I push into Heroku, there is no problem. But when I enter the site, my js library is not responding and thats where I get the error from above.

This is my **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>GEOIDE</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- FONTS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,800,800i">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i">

    <!-- jQUERY -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>


    <!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- VIEWPORT -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/viewport/jquery.viewport.js"></script>

    <!-- MENU -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/menu/hoverIntent.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/menu/superfish.js"></script>

    <!-- FANCYBOX -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="assets/plugins/fancyboxv3/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>-->

    <!-- REVOLUTION SLIDER  -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.actions.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.migration.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/revolutionslider/js/extensions/revolution.extension.video.min.js"></script>

    <!-- OWL Carousel -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- PARALLAX -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/parallax/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ISOTOPE -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/isotope/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/isotope/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

    <!-- PLACEHOLDER -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/placeholders/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>

    <!-- CONTACT FORM VALIDATE & SUBMIT -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/submit/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

    <!-- GOOGLE MAPS -->
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD3E-0gEeAoazgA2D7W0DAmPv1pYA5hPJ4"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/googlemaps/gmap3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- CHARTS -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/charts/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>

    <!-- COUNTER -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/counters/jquerysimplecounter.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/counters/odometer.min.js"></script>

    <!-- STATISTICS -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/statistics/chart.min.js"></script>

    <!-- INSTAFEED -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/instafeed/instafeed.min.js"></script>

    <!-- TWITTER -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/twitter/twitterfetcher.min.js"></script>

    <!-- YOUTUBE PLAYER -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/ytplayer/jquery.mb.ytplayer.min.js"></script>

    <!-- COUNTDOWN -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ANIMATIONS -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/animations/wow.min.js"></script>

    <!--Polyfill(s) for older browsers-->
    <script src="../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>-->

    <!-- CUSTOM JS -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
      <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**angular-cli.json**:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "geoide"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../src/assets/css/custom-styles.css",
        "../src/assets/css/pages-style.css",
        "../src/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../src/assets/fonts/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../src/assets/fonts/custom-icons/css/custom-icons.min.css",
        "../src/assets/fonts/custom-interface-icons/css/custom-interface-icons.min.css",
        "../src/assets/fonts/custom-office-icons/css/custom-office-icons.min.css",
        "../src/assets/fonts/custom-school-icons/css/custom-school-icons.min.css",
        "../src/assets/plugins/animations/animate.min.css",
        "../src/assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css",
        "../src/assets/plugins/revolutionslider/css/settings.css",
        "../src/assets/plugins/revolutionslider/css/layers.css",
        "../src/assets/plugins/revolutionslider/css/navigation.css",
        "../src/assets/plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css",
        "../src/assets/plugins/counters/odometer-theme-default.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

And **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "geoide",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot -prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.3",
    "npm": "3.10.10"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.